# VB.NET Resize programmatically created form

Tags: vb.net, forms, resize

I have form which is programmatically created.

Public declaration:

```
Public Form As Form
```

This code is inside sub

```
    Dim Form As New Form With
    {
        .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 58),
        .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
        .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
        .Size = New Size(546, 244)
    }
```

When i try to resize this form at runtime by clicking at button:

```
Form.Size = New Size(546, 455)

Form.Refresh()
```

It does not work.

EDIT:
I tried to rename `'Form'` to `'MyForm'` but nothing happened.

EDIT2: I'm creating my custom messages box. I have created module and inside this module is sub `CreateMsgBox(text As String, type As MsgType, Optional ex As String = "")` and in this sub is code which generating my form. After this code is few `AddHandler` statements with events like `Button_Click()` btw button is also created programmatically. I tried to change `Form.Size` to `Form.Location` to verify if button event works but location works only size not.

PS: Ahmed Abdelhameed If I replace `MyForm As New Form With` with `MyForm = New Form With`

1. It brokes my code for moving my form.
2. Form still not resizing.

I can not use `Me` because I do not have class.
Any ideas how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try naming your form variable something else other than `Form`?

Comment: Yes to 'MyForm', but nothing happened.

Comment: Well, you have a public variable of the form, but you don't use that when actually creating the form (and perhaps showing it?). Instead, you're creating a new one (with the same name). You should replace `Dim MyForm As New Form With` with `MyForm = New Form With`. Save yourself (and others) a lot of confusion and never create a variable with the same name of the type.

Comment: In your click event handler you need to have a reference to the Form (or myForm) created in the previous code. You should be able to reach this reference and apply the resize to the reference. Perhaps you should explain in which part of your code you are creating the form, where is the click code located and why you don't have a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you have a class level reference to the form but when you instantiate it, you are creating a local variable with the same name which shadows the class level one. I have written your code using the variable name `_window` for the form to avoid confusing it with anything else as follows

```
Private _window As Form
```

When creating it, I have this code...

```
_window = New Form With
{
    .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 58),
    .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
    .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
    .Size = New Size(546, 244)
}
_window.Show()
```

Then when resizing it, in a button click in the form that had the code to run it, I do this...

```
_window.Size = New Size(546, 455)
```

I'm not using refresh and the created form is resizing as expected.